# Find minimum number of coins that makes the given array

Tags: algorithm

### the problem

Input an integer array `A`, where `1<=A[i]<=1000000`.

Find the minimum size(cardinality) of a positive integer multiset `S` ( just like coins ), such that for every `A[i]`, there exist a subset of `S` whose sum equals `A[i]`.

#### example1

Input `A = [1,27,28]`.

Output `2`, one of the minimum multisets is `{1,27}`.

#### example2

Input `A=[18,37,42,50]`

Output `3`, the only minimum multisets is `{5,13,37}`

This test case shows that the `min(A)` don't appear in `S`, and the answer > `ceil(log2(len(A)))`.

### my question

Even if `len(A)<=10`, I can't find any correct and determined algorithm. Is there any solution that works when `len(A)` is about 10?

I can only find an algorithm that works when`len(A)<=6`:

For example, when `len(A)==6`, remove the duplicates from `A`. Suppose the size of `S` is `5`, then enumerate all possible coefficients `c00,c01,c02,c03,c04,c10,...`(cij∈{0,1}) in time complexity O(perm(32, 5)), such that `∑(cij*S[j])==A[i]` (0<=i<5). Solve the five linear equations using Gauss elimination in O(5^3), then additionally check `A[5]` using a knapsack algorithm. If there isn't a solution, the answer is 6, otherwise the size of `S` is at most 5. Repeating the previous process again, by assuming the size of `S` is 4. Until finding the correct solution.

Do such problems ( hard to write use brute force ) have some formal terminology?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243630/discussion-on-question-by-voyager-find-minimum-number-of-coins-that-makes-the-gi).

Answer (score 2):

In the following answer I will consider arrays `A` where all the values are strictly positive and that the values in the array are unique. First I would like to start by stating the relatively obvious.

1. If the array `A` has 2 numbers, the smallest set of numbers is two (the set `A` itself)
2. If the array `A` has 3 numbers, the smallest set of numbers will be 2 iff the sum of the smallest numbers equal to the third, otherwise it will be 3 (the set `A` itself)

After noting this I would like to look at the problem from the opposite direction, which will give us insights regarding the solution to our problem. Given a set of `n` numbers, a total of `2**n - 1` different numbers can be put together since each number in the set can be individually present or not in the summation.

### Example

Given a set of three numbers `{a,b,c}` a total of `2**3 - 1 = 7` numbers can be generated:

[a, b, c, a+b, a+c, b+c, a+b+c]

Therefore, we can derive a lower bound on the smallest set number given the length of `A`, noted as `m`:

Lower_bound = ceil(log2(m+1))

This means that the lower bound for `A` of length 4 to 7 is 3. The bound for lengths 8 to 15 is 4 etc.

### Solution suggestion

This will present a suggestion to a solution, it might has some flaws in it but it covered most of what I could come up with.

Since we now have a bound, if we find a set with length of the bound which solves our problem it is guaranteed to be an optimal and the result should be the bound.
I would suggest the following solution

1. for ss in range(3, m)

   1.1. get all combinations between `2` and `ss-1`, check if the sum of each combination is in the array. If  so, remove the sum from the array

   1.2. reduce from each remaining value in `A` all the rest of the remaining values, creating a symmetric rectangular matrix where the diagonal is 0

   1.3. for each possible combination of two positive values in the formed matrix check if:

   1.3.1. the sum of the combination is in `A`

   1.3.2. A number in A can be decomposed into two numbers with which it is possible to add with other members of `A`. If so, remove the three numbers from `A` and add the two decomposed numbers instead

A python implementation of this is as follows:

```py
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

def get_subset_count(A):
    m = len(A)
    if m == 2:
        return 2
    elif m == 3:
        return 3 if A[0] + A[1] == A[2] else 2
    else:
        lower_bound = int(np.ceil(np.log2(m + 1)))
        for ss in range(lower_bound, m): # checking if there is a subset with size of ss
            A_temp  = A.copy()
            removed = set()
            sub_values = []
            # phase 1 - looking if a summation of components in A result in other components in A
            for kk in range(2, ss+1):
                for comb in combinations(A[:ss+1, kk):
                    if sum(comb) in A_temp:
                        A_temp.remove(sum(comb))
                        removed.add(sum(comb))
            if len(A_temp) <= ss: return ss
            # phase 2 - looking for hidden base components
            deduction = np.array(A_temp)[:, None] - np.array(A_temp)
            for comb in combinations(deduction[deduction > 0].tolist(), 2):
                if sum(comb) in A_temp: # checking if the sum is in  the array
                    A_temp2 = A_temp.copy()
                    A_temp2.remove(sum(comb))
                    comb0_logic = [comb[0] + a in A_temp2 for a in A_temp2]
                    comb1_logic = [comb[1] + a in A_temp2 for a in A_temp2]
                    if any(comb0_logic) and any(comb1_logic): # checking if combination is a hidden base
                        A_temp.remove(sum(comb))
                        removed.add(sum(comb))
                        A_temp.remove(sum(comb[0] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb0_logic]))
                        removed.add(sum(comb[0] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb0_logic]))
                        sub_values = [comb[0]] + sub_values
                        if comb[0] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb0_logic] != comb[1] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb1_logic]:
                            A_temp.remove(sum(comb[1] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb1_logic]))
                            removed.add(sum(comb[1] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb1_logic]))
                        sub_values = [comb[1]] + sub_values
            if len(A_temp) + len(sub_values) <= ss: return ss
        return len(A)
```

When running this method with the following:

```py
A = [4,5,7,16]
print(get_subset_count(A))  # 3 - 4,5,7
A = [9,11,12,16]
print(get_subset_count(A))  # 3 - 4,5,7
A = [4,5,7,9,11,12,16]
print(get_subset_count(A))  # 3 - 4,5,7
A = [4,5,7,9,11,12,17]
print(get_subset_count(A))  # 4 - 4,5,7,17
A = [18,20,37,42,50]
print(get_subset_count(A))  # 4 - 5,13,20,37
A = [18,20,37,20,42,50,55]
print(get_subset_count(A))  # 4 - 5,13,20,37
A = [18,37,20,42,50,54]
print(get_subset_count(A))  # 5 - 18, 37, 20, 24, 30
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(get_subset_count(A))  # 4 - 1,2,3,4 or 1,2,4,8
```

Regarding runtime, this is NP in my opinion due to the `combinations` nature.

### Failing points

This method still fails to discover some of the samples, I'll explain with an example:

for `A = [4,13,21,37,45,62]` exists a lower bound set which is `[4,8,13,37]`. Denoting the set members as `[a,b,c,d]` respectively, we can describe `A` as

```
A = [a, c, c+b, d, d+b, a+b+c+d]
```

My suggested method will discover that `62 = 4+21+37` and will remove it, then it will *not* discover that `45 - 37 = 21 - 13 = 8`

### Improved suggestion

After looking for a solution to these cases as well, I came up with the following:

```py
def get_subset_count(A):
    m = len(A)
    if m == 2:
        return 2
    elif m == 3:
        return 3 if A[0] + A[1] == A[2] else 2
    else:
        lower_bound = int(np.ceil(np.log2(m + 1)))
        for ss in range(lower_bound, m): # checking if there is a subset with size of ss
            A_temp  = A.copy()
            removed = set()
            sub_values = []
            # phase 1 - looking if a summation of components in A result in other components in A
            for kk in range(2, ss+1):
                for comb in combinations(A[:ss+1], kk):
                    if sum(comb) in A_temp:
                        A_temp.remove(sum(comb))
                        removed.add(sum(comb))
            if len(A_temp) <= ss: return ss
            # phase 2 - looking for hidden base components
            deduction = np.array(A_temp)[:, None] - np.array(A_temp)
            for comb in combinations(deduction[deduction > 0].tolist(), 2):
                if sum(comb) in A_temp: # checking if the sum is in  the array
                    A_temp2 = A_temp.copy()
                    A_temp2.remove(sum(comb))
                    comb0_logic     = [comb[0] + a in A_temp2 for a in A_temp2]
                    comb0_logic_sub = [comb[0] + a in A_temp2 for a in sub_values]
                    comb1_logic     = [comb[1] + a in A_temp2 for a in A_temp2]
                    comb1_logic_sub = [comb[1] + a in A_temp2 for a in sub_values]
                    if any(comb0_logic) and any(comb1_logic): # checking if combination is a hidden base
                        A_temp.remove(sum(comb))
                        removed.add(sum(comb))
                        A_temp.remove(sum(comb[0] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb0_logic]))
                        removed.add(sum(comb[0] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb0_logic]))
                        if comb[0] not in sub_values: sub_values.append(comb[0])  # if this sub value is not in the list, adding it
                        if comb[0] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb0_logic] != comb[1] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb1_logic]:
                            A_temp.remove(sum(comb[1] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb1_logic]))
                            removed.add(sum(comb[1] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb1_logic]))
                        if comb[1] not in sub_values: sub_values.append(comb[1])  # if this sub value is not in the list, adding it
                    elif (comb[0] in sub_values) or (comb[1] in sub_values):
                        if any(comb0_logic_sub):
                            A_temp.remove(sum(comb[0] + np.array(sub_values)[comb0_logic_sub]))
                            removed.add(sum(comb[0] + np.array(sub_values)[comb0_logic_sub]))
                            if comb[0] not in sub_values: sub_values.append(comb[0])  # if this sub value is not in the list, adding it
                        if any(comb1_logic_sub):
                            A_temp.remove(sum(comb[1] + np.array(sub_values)[comb1_logic_sub]))
                            removed.add(sum(comb[1] + np.array(sub_values)[comb1_logic_sub]))
                            if comb[1] not in sub_values: sub_values.append(comb[1])  # if this sub value is not in the list, adding it
                elif comb[0] == comb[1]:  # cases where the hidden base is not in the set but the sum of the hidden base with other parts are in the set
                    A_temp2 = A_temp.copy()
                    comb0_logic = [comb[0] + a in A_temp2 for a in A_temp2]
                    if any(comb0_logic):
                        removed_numbers = comb[0] + np.array(A_temp2)[comb0_logic]
                        for removed_number in removed_numbers:
                            A_temp.remove(removed_number)
                            removed.add(removed_number)
                    if comb[0] not in sub_values: sub_values.append(comb[0])
                elif comb[0] in sub_values and comb[1] in sub_values and sum(comb) in A_temp:  # cases where we found the base already and we need to remove a single number
                    A_temp.remove(sum(comb))
                    removed.add(sum(comb))
            # phase 3 - check if we did not forget any other number due to the order of combinations
            for kk in range(2, ss+1):
                for comb in combinations(sub_values, kk):
                    if sum(comb) in A_temp:
                        A_temp.remove(sum(comb))
            if len(A_temp) + len(sub_values) <= ss: return ss
        return len(A)
```

Comment: WA on testcase A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; output 10 expected <=4

Comment: @Voyager Fixed it, should work now for this case (and another one I found to be not working)

Comment: Can you clarify what the flaws are in this suggested solution? Since you seem to be iterating over the set of all possible combinations, it wasn't clear why there should be any cases where this doesn't work. Yet this has WA on testcase `[4, 13, 21, 37, 45, 62]`, with output 5 with expected 4 (with [4, 8, 13, 37], for example)

Comment: @kcsquared I added an explanation for that, thank you very much for your feedback